# Cannot connect to mysql Local database after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, 20.04

I cannot connect to MYSQL db and it is a root process:

I have tried the solution:

1. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11027/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

but failed

Status of mysql server:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-05-26 15:01:53 IST; 23min ago
Process: 1470 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1479 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 26 15:01:53 user systemd[1]: 
mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
May 26 15:01:53 user systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 26 15:01:53 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 15:01:53 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 15:01:53 user systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Could you please post the output when you run "mysql -u user -p " command ?

Comment: "mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly" is because of the fast restarting the service . For example you were running the command " service mysql restart " repeatedly and very fast.

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Comment: Can you run "sudo  /usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre" and then " sudo -u mysql /usr/sbin/mysqld " and then see the output ? Those are the commands that get executed when you start the service.

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: If it's possible backup all of your databases and consider re-installing the mysql package. I have installed it from the official [mysql repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and works well in 18.04 . Your problem might be caused by using different versions for the server and client or an incomplete system update.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04 for reinstallation one can use following link